# Ошибка автозагрузки sh скрипта

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

Делал по [инструкции](https://losst.ru/avtozagruzka-linux).Раздел - АВТОЗАГРУЗКА СКРИПТОВ В LINUX. Когда запускаю получаю. Задача - автозагрузка при старте raspberry.

```
runscript.service          loaded failed failed    My Bot
```

@Dejsving

```
    Linux version 4.9.35-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.9.35-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:    8.0
Codename:   jessie
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос вывод одной из следующих команд (cat /proc/version; dmesg | grep "Linux version"; lsb_release -a; cat /etc/*-release) и какие действия из статьи Вы совершали

Comment: скрипт покажите и `journalctl -u runscript.service`

Comment: Окей. Запущу расп завтра и скину. Действия как по инструкции по ссылке.

Comment: У вас ошибка в копи-пасте не "at /proc/version," а "cat /proc/version"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в /etc/xdg/autostart создать выражаясь терминологиями M$ ярлык на файлик

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=ИМЯ
Comment=
Exec=Чего выполнить
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```